# Uploading a file with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file, upload

I´ve been looking at all the answers i could find in here, but none seems to work for me, not sure why.

I´m trying to upload a file using ajax, but the file never gets to the $_FILES array in PHP, i only makes it to the $_POST array but it won´t let me get the name or size of the file. I've tried every single solution answered here but none seems to solve my problem and i'm not sure why, i think there is something i'm not seeing. If anyone can help me that would be awesome.

THE HTML CODE

```
<form name='formuploadgraphic'>
     <input type='file' name='archivo1' id='archivo1' onchange='subegraphic()'>
</form>
```

THE JS/AJAX CODE

```
function subegraphic()
{
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("archivo1", $("#formuploadgraphic")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "subegraphic.php",
        type: "post",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: true
    })
     .done(
         function(data)
         {
             alert(data);
         }
     );
}
```

THE PHP CODE

```
<?php
    $upload_folder ='graphics';
    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archivo1']['name'];
    $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo1']['type'];
    $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archivo1']['size'];
    $tmp_archivo = $_FILES['archivo1']['tmp_name'];
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['archivo1']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $archivador = $upload_folder . '/' . $nombre_archivo;
    echo $nombre_archivo;
?>
```

This is the reply from the php if i use that code:

"
**Notice**:  Undefined index: archivo1 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\airpost\home\subegraphic.php** on line **4**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: archivo1 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\airpost\home\subegraphic.php** on line **5**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: archivo1 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\airpost\home\subegraphic.php** on line **6**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: archivo1 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\airpost\home\subegraphic.php** on line **7**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: archivo1 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\airpost\home\subegraphic.php** on line **8**
"

If anyone can tell what is the problem with my code that would be grate. Thx in advance.

PS: upload files is ON in the php.ini

Comment: Have you tried [this tutorial](https://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery)? I would be interested in an answer to your question as well, as I have a similar dilemma at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Code Snippet you posted, your jQuery selector is pointing to an `undefined` element

Change

```
formData.append("archivo1", $("#formuploadgraphic")[0]);
```

to

```
formData.append("archivo1", $("#archivo1").prop('files')[0]);
```

Comment: I just tested your fix and id didn't fixed, but it was like 99% of the solution, the problem was indeed the selector, so i tried different solutions, until i added the [0], since i'm only sending one file at a time, this worked like a charm. So the line changed to: <code>formData.append("archivo1", $("#formuploadgraphic").files[0]); </code>and it worked. Ok i have no idead how to set that as code in an answer but it really worked, so thanks a lot

Comment: My Bad, i missed that when typing in the answer. I have now edited the original answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing this line

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("archivo1", $("#formuploadgraphic")[0]);
```

To

```
var formData = new FormData($("#formuploadgraphic")[0]);
```

and also adding ***enctype="multipart/form-data"*** to your form attribute

```
<form name='formuploadgraphic' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Ok i implemented both changes and i'm still getting the same response, i can't seem to find the problem with that code